# sklearn agglomerative clustering: distancing between clusters

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose that sklearn's [AgglomerativeClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) has returned with 10 clusters. Is there a way to get at some pairwise distances among the 10 clusters?

Specifically, given that there are 10 clusters, the result should be something like a 10 x 10 matrix, or at least an enumeration of the pairwise distances. I tried the method distances_ but the dimension seems wrong (it's m x 1 where m is the number of input atoms to be clustered).